# Pass parameter via URL to pre-select drop down value on linked page

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, url-parameters

I am looking to click a link (Click Here for Option 3) where the resulting page will have the appropriate pre-selected value (**option 3**) in the drop down.  The drop down code on the landing page is as follows:

```
<select id="mySelect" name="mySelect">
    <option>Portal Selector</option>
    <option>CSR24</option>
    <option>MyWave</option>
    <option>HR Connection</option>
    <option>CertFocus</option>
</select>
```

I have tried JavaScript, but have not come up with any successful code.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The following code works, but it is only for a drop down that appears on the same page.  How can I force this value to pass as a parameter in a URL?

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Here</button>
<script>
    function myFunction()
    {
        document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex="3";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a parameter in the URL and accessing it through `location.href` and setting the `selectedIndex` through that value?

Comment: You could also do this through cookies.

Comment: I may not have explained the question properly.  One page contains the link "Click Here."  I need this link to reference page http://www.mysite.com/ and pre-select option number 3 in the drop down on the landing page.